# difference between Java TCP Sockets and C TCP Sockets while trying to connect to JDBC

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp, proxy

My problem is that C sockets look to act differently than Java sockets. I have a C proxy and I tested it between a workload generator (oltp benchmark client written in Java) and the JDBC connector of the Postgres DB.
This works great and forwards data from one to other, as it should. We need to make this proxy work in Java, so I used plain ServerSocket and Socket classes from java.net and I cannot make it work. The Postgres returns an authentication error message, assuming that the client did not send the correct password.

Here is how the authentication at the JDBC protocol works:

-client sends a requests to connect to a database specifying the database name and the username

-server responds back with a one time challenge message (13 byte message with random content)

-client concatenates this message with the user password and performs a md5 hash

-server compares the hash got from the client with the hash he computes

[This procedure is performed in order to avoid replay attacks (if client would send only the md5 hash of its password then an attacker could replay this message, pretending he is the client)]

So I inspected the packets with tcpdump and they look correct! The size is exactly as it should, so maybe the content is corrupted (??)

Sometimes though the DB server responds ok for the authentication (depending on the value of the challenge message)!! And then the oltp client sends a couple of queries, but it crashes in a while…
I guess that maybe it has to do with the encoding, so I tried with the encoding that C uses (US-ANSII), but still the same.

I send the data using fixed size character or byte arrays both in C and in Java!

I really don't have any more ideas, as I tried so many cases...

What is your guess of what would be the problem?

Here is a representative code that may help you have a more clear view:

```
byte [] msgBuf;
char [] msgBufChars;
while(fromInputReader.ready()){
    msgBuf = new byte[1024];
    msgBufChars = new char[1024];
    // read data from one party
    int read = fromInputReader.read(msgBufChars, 0, 1024);
    System.out.println("Read returned : " + read);
    for(int i=0; i<1024; i++)
        msgBuf[i] = (byte) msgBufChars[i];
    String messageRead = new String(msgBufChars);
    String messageToWrite = new String(msgBuf);
    System.out.println("message read : "+messageRead);
    System.out.println("message to write : "+new String(messageToWrite));
    // immediatelly write data to other party (write the amount of data we read (read value) )
    // there is no write method that takes a char [] as a parameter, so pass a byte []
    toDataOutputStream.write(msgBuf, 0, read);
    toDataOutputStream.flush();
}
```

There are a couple of message exchanges in the beginning and then Postgres responds with an authentication failure message.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: don't use Reader for input, use InputStream to deal with raw bytes, so you won't change any bytes through string encoding/decoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is your guess of what would be the problem?

It is nothing to do with C versus Java sockets.  It is everything to do with bad Java code.

I can see some problems:

- You are using a Reader in what should be a binary stream.  This is going to result in the data being converted from bytes (from the JDBC client) to characters and then back to bytes.  Depending on the character set used by the reader, this is *likely* to be destructive.

  You should use plain, unadorned<sup>1</sup> input streams for both reading and writing, and you should read / write to / from a preallocated `byte[]`.
- This is terrible:

  ```
  for(int i=0; i<1024; i++)
      msgBuf[i] = (byte) msgBufChars[i];
  ```

  1. If the characters you read are not in the range `0 ... 255` you are mangling them when you stuff them into `msgBuf`.
  2. You are *assuming* that you actually got 1024 characters.
- You are using the `ready()` method to decide when to stop reading stuff.  This is almost certainly wrong.  Read the javadoc for that method (and think about it) and you should understand why it is wrong.  (Hint: what happens if the proxy can read faster than the client can deliver?)

  You should use a `while(true)`, and then break out of the loop if `read` tells you it has reached the end of stream; i.e. if it returns `-1` ...

---

<sup>1 - Just use the stream objects that the Socket API provides.  `DataXxxStream` is unnecessary because the `read` and `write` methods are simply call-throughs.  I wouldn't even use `BufferedXxxStream` wrappers in this case, because you are already doing your own buffering using the byte array.</sup>

---

Here's how I'd write that code:

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];  // or bigger
while(true) {
    int nosRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
    if (nosRead < 0) {
        break;
    }

    // Note that this is a bit dodgy, given that the data you are converting is
    // binary.  However, if the purpose is to see what embedded character data 
    // looks like, and if the proxy's charset matches the text charset used by 
    // the client-side JDBC driver for encoding data, this should achieve that.
    System.out.println("Read returned : " + nosRead);
    System.out.println("message read : " + new String(buffer, 0, nosRead));

    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, nosRead);
    outputStream.flush();
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you!
I was typecasting each char to a byte because they have the same size (1 byte each), but you are right that it is possible to lose some information.
To be honest I didn't notice that DataInputStream offers a read method for reading to a byte[] (in the beginning I used to read integers one at a time, instead of a fixed size buffer), that's why I was doing the conversion from char to byte...
So with having DataInputStream to read and DataOutputStream to write to fixed size byte[] it works perfectly!
Thanks a lot for your comments!

Comment: Updated my answer to point out that using DataInputStream and DataOutputStream is unnecessary ... though it is probably harmless.

Answer (score 1):

> C sockets look to act differently than Java sockets.

Impossible. Java sockets are just a very thin layer over C sockets. You're on the wrong track with this line of thinking.

```
byte [] msgBuf;
char [] msgBufChars;
```

Why are you reading chars when you want to write bytes? Don't use `Readers` unless you know that the input is text.

And don't call ready(). There are very few correct uses, and this isn't one of them. Just block.

Comment: You are right, but I performed deep packet inspection and could not find anything wrong in the contents of the packets! That's why I thought that Java requires to tweak some settings in order to transfer packets in the desired format.
Thanks for the comments!